# Transaction log full due to CHECKPOINT

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I see that posts already exists for this type of issue, but they are not 100% identical to the one I have here. The solutions proposed also don't work. (I have tried a lot...)

I'm trying to restore functionality of a database that is practically locked due to the error:

> Transaction log for database 'dbname' is full due to 'CHECKPOINT'.

Any query I try that involves ALTER database fails, and gives me the mentioned error, meaning I am not allowed to backup, shrink, change recovery model or increase allocated log space on the database or log affected. Setting the database in emergency mode doesn't work either.

This is SQL Express2014
The database is set to simple recovery model.

What is curious is when I run `DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)` it says that the database is using 100.6312% log space, and another associated database is using 106.3655% log space. They  have somehow exceeded their limits, or the limits have been changed and set too low.

How does this happen? And how can it be resolved?

I can read the database tables, so I'm afraid the only option here would be to have something read everything and write to a new database.

Comment: Can you CHECKPOINT the database?  In simple recovery the log cannot be reused until the dirty pages are flushed to disk. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/checkpoint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16